# Add past date to auto_now_add

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a model in which I have field like this

```
createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I have to populate records with past date lets say like `1990-01-01` 
So I am doing

```
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime('1990-01-01',"%Y-%m-%d")
Model.objects.create(createdDate=dt)
```

but it is coming as current date and time how can I add past dated datetime to this field?

Can I however turn off the auto_now_add for while and switch it back dynamically

Comment: You just set the `.createDate` attribute of the objects you want to "inject" in the database.

Comment: I am trying that in `Model.objects.create(createdDate='1990-01-01')` but it is taking the current date @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add),

> Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored.

So, instead of `auto_now_add`, use `default`.

```
createdDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
```